# Confusion using XmlSerializer with abstract data request

Tags: c#, xmlserializer, typeof

I am new to C# and this question seems dubious but please bear with me. I have an `XmlSerializer` that works perfectly when written as follows *(small code snippet)* :

```
 public static AbstractResponseMessageData Execute(AbstractRequestMessageData objRQ, string strComponent)
    {
        StreamWriter rqWriter = null;
        StreamReader rsReader = null;
        try
        {
            Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor;

            String requestType = objRQ.GetType().Name;
            MessageBox.Show(requestType);

            String xmlRequest = "";
            var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ARC_LOGONRQ));
```

Unforunately, as `ARC_LOGONRQ` is a type from an abstract data request, it is not the case that it is always the type I am needing. The only way I even knew it was the type that would get this first request to work was by using the `MessageBox` in my code. I figured I would simply write something like this to circumvent the issue:

```
Type acType = Type.GetType(requestType);
```

and then use `acType` instead of `ARC_LOGONRQ` in my serializer. That throws a **"Type or Namespace could not be found"** error however. Replacing `ARC_LOGONRQ` with `objRQ.GetType()` or `objRQ` throws the same error as well. 
I do not understand why I get this error when using `acType`, nor how I should properly go about serializing `objRQ` without specifying the actual data type (*which I can't do*). 

Many thanks.

**FURTHER INFO:**
Using the serializer:

```
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(objRQ.GetType()));
```

I also get a **"Type or Namespace could not be found"** error. I think it is because the type `ARC_LOGONRQ` appears to be arbitrary, or not in System.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always get the `Type` of an object by calling [`GetType`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gettype%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  Try this:

```
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(objRQ.GetType());
```

Use `typeof` to obtain a `Type` at compile time.  Use `GetType` to obtain a `Type` at run time  .

Comment: See my example.  Remove the `typeof()` from your code.

Comment: Oh my goodness. The most simple thing just stumped me for a good hour. Many many thanks.